# Assigning a Variable to an Underscore in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

After researching stackoverflow about underscores in Swift I understand that an underscore means a) ignore this function and b) you can omit the parameter name when using the method.  What I don't understand is what happens if we assign a variable to an underscore?  By assigning an underscore to a variable, this silences the compiler warning from Xcode that reads "result of initializer is unused" but it doesn't show warnings if you don't use this variable in any way.

Is this variable still created and stored in memory or is it ignored by the compiler all together as if it were a line of code that is commented out?

For example:

```
func test_ToDoItem_TakesTitle(){

        let firstToDoItem = ToDoItem(title: "First Instance Title")

        _ = ToDoItem(title: "First ToDoItem instance")

        XCTAssertEqual(firstToDoItem.title, "First Instance Title")

    }
```

Is the following line of code created and stored in memory or ignored:

```
 _ = ToDoItem(title: "First ToDoItem instance")
```

Hopefully this question makes sense because I'd like to become mindful of how each piece of memory is used in Xcode.

Comment: The function still executes, however, since there is no reference to it, the memory will be immediately reclaimed by ARC. Here's the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0047-nonvoid-warn.md) for this behavior

Comment: @CodeDifferent, apparently not immediately.  It seems to wait until the item goes out of scope.  See my answer for a demo.

Comment: Oh wow @CodeDifferent the link you provided called 'proposal', is this the open source github repository where people offer suggestions to the swift language and Apple reads them?  If so, I've heard of this through podcasts but just wanted to be sure this was it.

Comment: Indeed. That's where people make proposals to change the Swift language. The discussions take place on the mailing lists and you can see the final results reflected on that GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test shows that the object is created and then destroyed when the object goes out of scope:

```
class ToDoItem {
    var title = ""

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit \(title)")
    }
}

func test() {
    print("test")

    _ = ToDoItem(title: "First")
    _ = ToDoItem(title: "Second")

    print("end test")
}

func callTest() {
    print("calling test()...")
    test()
    print("back from test()")
}

callTest()
```

Output:

> ```
> calling test()...
> test
> end test
> deinit Second
> deinit First
> back from test()
> ```

---

**Extended test:**

```
func test() {
    print("test")

    _ = ToDoItem(title: "Item 1")
    for i in 2...4 {
        _ = ToDoItem(title: "Item \(i)")
    }
    _ = ToDoItem(title: "Item 5")

    print("end test")
}
```

> ```
> calling test()...
> test
> deinit Item 2
> deinit Item 3
> deinit Item 4
> end test
> deinit Item 5
> deinit Item 1
> back from test()
> ```

Notice that items 2, 3 and 4 are deinitialized as they go out of scope in each loop.  Items 1 and 5 are deinitialized when they go out of scope when `test()` completes.

---

**Inside of an App**

As Dmitry Plotnikov noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529216/1630618), the above is true only in a Swift Playground.  In an app, the results are:

> ```
> calling test()...
> test
> deinit Item 1
> deinit Item 2
> deinit Item 3
> deinit Item 4
> deinit Item 5
> end test
> back from test()
> ```

That tells us:

1. The objects are created.
2. They are freed immediately.

Comment: Much obliged, not sure if you made the edit but the first example made sense for sure.

Comment: Oh wow, that definitely put more emphasis on memory in regards to scope.

Comment: For people who ran into this issue and want to silence the unused variable warning you can just assign the variable to _ at the end of the scope. "_ = toDoItem"

Answer (score 4):

> Is this variable still created and stored in memory or is it ignored by the compiler all together as if it were a line of code that is commented out?

It all depends on the implementation of the `ToDoItem` class.

The line seems to be redundant on first sight. But think about this, what if there is something that is in the initializer of `ToDoItem` that you want executed? The only way to have that executed is to create a new instance of `ToDoItem` but writing `ToDoItem(...)` alone would cause a warning. That's why you use the wildcard pattern to silence the warning.

This is especially useful in CoreData. Sometimes you only want to save a new managed object without changing any of the properties. You would write:

```
_ = MyEntity(entity: ..., insertInto: ...)
```

because you just want the side effect of the initializer - saving a new managed object.

If the initializer of `ToDoItem` assigns `self` to something else, then yes, the `ToDoItem` will be in memory. For example,

```
SomeClass.someStaticProperty = self
```

If you don't do that, `ToDoItem` will be deinitialized

Comment: Great, great example because you described it in terms of Core Data which I'd like to learn in the future.  Question though?  Would "SomeClass.someStaticProperty = self" create a retain cycle or are retain cycle only created when one object has a reference to a completely different object? @Sweeper

Comment: @user6510422 No, there will not be a retain cycle because `someStaticProperty` is static. You can set `SomeClass.someStaticProperty` to `nil` to deinitialize `ToDoItem`. _are retain cycle only created when one object has a reference to a completely different object?_ Not neccessarily. I think if an object holds a reference to itself a retain cycle will be created as well, not to mention that there are many kinds of retain cycles.

Answer (score 2):

As vacawama mentioned in his answer, the object is created and then destroyed when the object goes out of scope.

**BUT** this is only true for the code executed in a playground. When executed withing an app on Simulator or on a device the object is destroyed immediately. *Beware!*

I used the following code from vacawama’s answer for test:

```
class ToDoItem {
    var title = ""

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit \(title)")
    }
}

func test() {
    print("test")

    _ = ToDoItem(title: "First")
    _ = ToDoItem(title: "Second")

    print("end test")
}

func callTest() {
    print("calling test()...")
    test()
    print("back from test()")
}

callTest()
```

(Sorry I cannot comment on the other answer yet; though I though this was an important one to share)

Comment: I still don’t know how to suppress the “unused” warning if I need the object to live within the scope though, because in that case I am forced to assign it to `let temp = ...`

Comment: this seems to be the correct answer. at least in swift 8.2 and swift 3

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  I understand that you couldn't comment on my answer, but I would have appreciated it if someone would have.  Alas, I found out because someone down voted without leaving a comment as to why.  Since my answer is the accepted one, I note your results and link to your answer.